# New Line in Excel Chart Legend?

Tags: excel, charts, legend, excel-interop

It is possible to add a new line to an excel legend using Excel or programmaticaly using Excel.Interop (VB.NET or C#)?

I want to have the legend items in 2 languages, one  word under the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Alt+Enter to separate different languages in the data source cells, you can have multiple languages in labels for data points and in the legend.

[image]